# Manually control the perspective of an object (mesh) in Three.JS

Tags: three.js

I'm building a spaceship game and am having some issues controlling how the ship moves.

I would like to move the ship (a mesh) around the screen controlling the x and y position.   But rather than the perspective being calculated automatically, I would like to control the rotation properties myself.  Basically always keeping a flat mesh what ever its x and y position within the world and overriding its perspective.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized '.lookAt(vector)' sorted my problem. See http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_lookat.html